# vue-i18n Cannot translate the value of keypath. Use the value of keypath as default

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have this error and I dont know what is the value of keypath. I already tried to import messages array and defined in the `data()` the `i18n locale`, but it didn't work.

**main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import {routes} from './routes.js';
import {messages} from './i18n.js';

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

**Main.vue**

```html
<template>
<div class="col-md-6 col-12 text-white">
    <h2>new h2</h2>
    <p>{{ $t('welcomeMsg') }}</p>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {};
</script>
```

**i18n.js**

```js
const messages = {
    "en": {welcomeMsg: 'Welcome to EN'},
    "es": {welcomeMsg: 'Welcome to ES'}
};
```

**Navbar.vue**

```html
<template>
    <a v-on:click="changeLocale('es')">EN</a>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        methods: {
            changeLocale: function(locale) {
                if(locale == "en"){
                    this.$i18n.locale = "es";
                }else{
                    this.$i18n.locale = "en";
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If you console.log(messages) in main.js you'll see it's currently undefined. This is because you haven't exported your messages from i18n.js:

export const messages = {
    "en": {welcomeMsg: 'Welcome to EN'},
    "es": {welcomeMsg: 'Welcome to ES'}
};

Comment: Oh really... I thought I did. Thank you for your help!